# Using MUI DataGrid, how to update a cell state onChange?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

What I need: I'm using MUI DataGrid > 5. I need that the data that is filled in a cell change automatically the state (`onChange`). At this moment, I have an `useEffect` that is listening to these changes to “enable/disable” the “Save” and “Cancel” buttons.

What I tried: Using `onCellEditCommit` property, it saves the cell content only when I click outside the DataGrid component (or when I press tab or enter). I would like to save the content on cell change.

```
...
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridPreProcessEditCellProps,
  GridRowId,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
...

const [devices, setDevices] = useState<Device[]>(formValues.devices);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "id",
      headerName: "ID",
      flex: 10,
    },
    {
      field: "uniqueIdentification",
      headerName: "Unique ID",
      editable: true,
      flex: 30,
    },
    {
      field: "description",
      headerName: "Description",
      editable: true,
      flex: 50,
    },
    {
      field: "isActive",
      headerName: "Active",
      type: "boolean",
      editable: true,
      flex: 10,
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: "actions",
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <Box id={`${params.id}`} component="div">
          <IconButton
            title="Remove"
            onClick={() => deleteRow(params.id)}
            size="small"
          >
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      ),
    },
  ];

  function saveDeviceCell(params) {
    const oldDevices = [...devices];

    const rowDeviceIndex = oldDevices.findIndex((dev) => dev.id === params.id);

    oldDevices[rowDeviceIndex] = {
      ...oldDevices[rowDeviceIndex],
      [params.field]: params.value,
    };

    setDevices(oldDevices);
  }

...
return (
  <DataGrid
     rows={devices}
     columns={columns}
     hideFooterPagination
     hideFooter
     disableSelectionOnClick
     autoHeight
     onCellEditCommit={saveDeviceCell}
     editMode="cell"
  />
...
);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ?